# Unique table constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-constraint, unique-key, unique-index

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `b1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `b1` (`b1`,`b2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here, the unique table constraint is given for 2 fields. But, in the show create table query, it is like *UNIQUE KEY `b1` (`b1`,`b2`)* Also the first field `b1` acts as a unique key in which `b2` is combined.

I could drop the constraint of `b1` but not `b2`:

```
mysql> alter table b drop index b2;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'b2'; check that column/key exists

mysql> alter table b drop index b1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answers needed for :

1. Why this unique constraint is applied only for one field(first mentioned field)?
2. Is the structure of unique table constraint like that?
3. Any attachments of reference links is much needed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your case `b1` just name for UNIQUE KEY. Because you give not name for constraint at create table statement it named implicitly by first column name (`b1`). It steel check for uniqueness for pair `b1` and `b2`
For create named key you can use next statement:

```
create table b (
  b1 int, b2 int, 
  unique key b1b2_uk (b1,b2)
);
```

Here created `unique key` named `b1b2_uk`

Look example [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a60d4fd91d456b75302c5646a7f4e9d3&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

If you want to remove constraint you should use it's name like:

```
alter table b drop index b1b2_uk;
```

For change constraint you need to drop exist and create new one like:

```
alter table b 
    drop index b1b2_uk,
    add primary key b1_pk (b1);
```

Look fiddle on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d628c6e197bc5b68ef413c604eba7272&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier to understand if the table looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `b1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `my_unique_index` (`b1`,`b2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

alter table b drop index my_unique_index;
```

Get it?